# Decorator Beginner __name__ is causing Type error

Tags: python, decorator

I have tried a few things to see if it had to do with when the functions were defined but to no avail I could not solve this. I am 90% sure the "**name**" method is causing the issue. But to me, this seems like it would be a good way to use a wrapper? Trying to explore wrapper because I am currently learning flask and they use wrappers off the get go with subdirectories. Thank you in advanced.

```
def smartCalc(func):
    def inner(a, b):
        if func.__name__ == "divide":
            print("I am going to divide" + str(a) + "and" + str(b))
            if b == 0:
                print("whoops! cannot divide")
                return
            return func(a, b)
        
        if func.__name__ == "Add":
            print("I am going to add", a, "and", b)
            return func(a, b)
        return inner



@smartCalc
def divide(a, b):
    print(a/b)

@smartCalc
def Add(a, b):
    print(a+b)



Add(3,1)
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
I was somewhat following [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator) when I wanted to try something.

Comment: `if func.__name__ == "Add":` where is that code ? PLease fix indentation

Comment: Fix indendation because code should work

Comment: you need to unindent `return inner` one level

Comment: @timgeb Thanks guys. Should have been obvious I was looking at this for so long. Probably time for a little break!

Answer (score 1):

You need to unindent the `return inner`, and execute `func` in all cases finally

```
def smartCalc(func):
    def inner(a, b):
        if func.__name__ == "divide":
            print("I am going to divide", a, "and", b)
            if b == 0:
                print("whoops! cannot divide")
                return
        if func.__name__ == "Add":
            print("I am going to add", a, "and", b)

        return func(a, b)

    return inner
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `smartCalc` defines an inner function, and then doesn't do anything else. It doesn't call the inner function, nor does it return something. So it always returns None.

Remember how

```py
@smartCalc
def Add(a, b):
    print(a+b)
```

is just a fancy way of writing

```py
def Add(a, b):
    print(a+b)
Add = smartCalc(Add)
```

? Well, now `Add` is `None`, so you can't call it anymore.

Comment: it's `divide = smartCalc(divide(a, b))`

Comment: @sahasrara62 No. a and b don't even exist at that point.

Comment: its `divide = smartCalc(divide(1,2))` when you call `data=divide(1,2)` here OP hasn't call divide function so it doesn't called only add is

Comment: @sahasrara62 I changed my explanation to use the Add function. Doesn't really matter. Does that clean up your confusion?